# How to convert 2D array board into Isometric board

Tags: java

im new to java and really interested in game design, I have drawn a 2D array board using Graphic drawRect, and I want to convert this 2D array board into an isometric board. I have searched through stack overflow but the implementation is confusing since im new.

Any tips and hints is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: it is the same, just calculate the positions with some simple  trigonometry. mind you the angle should match the angle used in your images

Comment: will be much easier if you give it a try and come back with some specific problem

Comment: The best tip is to google "java isometric tutorial" and get some useful [links](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511)

Comment: I think you mean [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvSjJ-kdGio).